# Python multiprocess app accessing same shared library call

Tags: python, multithreading, ubuntu, multiprocessing

In my python program i am trying to call a shared library function in different threads but it stops after a few seconds. What will be the problem?

```
def FnVDC1(l, delay): 
    while True:   
        l.acquire()
        try:
            ret_check = libCAN.WriteCANMessage(handle, byref(VDC1))
        finally:
            l.release()
        time.sleep(delay)

def FnEEC1( l, delay):    
    while True:   
        l.acquire()
        try:
            ret_check = libCAN.WriteCANMessage(handle, byref(EEC1))
        finally:
            l.release()
        time.sleep(delay)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lock = RLock()
    ThVDC1 = multiprocessing.Process(name='VDC1', target=FnVDC1, args=(lock,.200))
    ThEEC1 = multiprocessing.Process(name='EEC1', target=FnEEC1, args=(lock,.250))

    ThVDC1.start()
    ThEEC1.start()
```

So both the threads calls libCAN.WriteCANMessage at seperate intervals one at 200ms and another at 250ms.It works for a few seconds and then suddenly stops.What can be the reason? What is the proper solution to solve this issue? I will be adding eight more threads like this. I am using Ubuntu OS.

Comment: What do you mean 'it suddenly stops'? Where does the RLock class come from (show the import please)?

Comment: As a side note, you can use locks with the with-statement, to make your code slightly shorter/more readable. E.g. `with l:    do_stuff()`, which will handle acquiring and releasing the lock for you.

Comment: @TomDalton from multiprocessing import RLock

Comment: @Tom Dalton 3  i didn't understand how "with 1" solves the thread stopping issue.

Comment: It doesn't, I'm just saying it's a slightly neater way to use locks. Also, you don't need (from what I can see) an `RLock`, a `Lock` would suffice. Finally, we still need more information on what "it suddenly stops" really means.